# How does sorting a C# List based on a property work?

Tags: c#, list, sorting, properties, field

So, I'm doing an assignment for my C# class and I have a list of objects. These objects have an 'int rand' field which is assigned a random number. I then wanted to re-sort the objects in the list based on this rand field.

I found this article:
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5513/sorting-and-searching-using-c-lists/

And it helped. I modified this line to fit my code:

```
people.Sort(delegate(Person p1, Person p2) { return p1.age.CompareTo(p2.age); });
```

And it does what I want.

What I want to know is: how does it work? That looks very confusing to me.

Comment: Note that this isn't the most efficient way to shuffle the order of the elements in a list.

Comment: The code will call your method, `delegate(Person p1, Person p2) { return p1.age.CompareTo(p2.age); }` on each pair of items it wishes to compare.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# - sorting by a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147082/c-sharp-sorting-by-a-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact Sort Method should sort base on some comparison, in your current code you passed comparison as delegate, you can also embed it in class definition to reduce code complexity, In fact it just needed to implement IComparable for your `Person` class:

```
 public class Person : IComparable
    {
        public int age { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            var person = obj as Person;
            if (person != null)
            {
                if (age > person.age)
                    return 1;
                else if (age == person.age)
                    return 0;
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

then simply use sort without delegates.

Comment: Unless his assignment requires him to use delegates, I would do this too.

Comment: This is not always the case, what if you want to sort `People` by `age` or by `name`, depending on user choice?

Comment: @Miguel Angelo yes, but is good to have a default comparison method and for other comparison types use delegates or lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Lambda notation with it gets a little easier to read IMO:

```
people.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.age.CompareTo(p2.age));
```

When you use the sort method you are sorting the list, but the method needs to know what to sort by, and this is where the delegation becomes handy as you can use the sort method to specify any sorting you want.  You are looking at person 1 and person 2 and are ordering by age.  If you wanted to sort by something else like a Name (If you had a Name property), you would write it as:

```
people.Sort((p1, p2) => string.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

the list will use the function passed in (the `return p1.age.CompareTo(p2.age);` part) to compare the different objects in the list.  It basically allows you to "teach" the list how you want the items compared.

The list will call your function, passing in 2 instances of the class that should be compared. you return -1 to say the 1st is less than the 2nd, 0 to say they are equal, and 1 to say the 2nd is greater.  Your example just passes the call on to the built in comparison (that returns the same -1, 0, 1 pattern) for whatever type the age variable is, most likely an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort, you need to be able to figure out if one item goes before or after another thing. It makes sense that this "comparator" would be a function or method as it compartmentalizes the knowledge away.

If you look at the documentation for `CompareTo` you'll notice that it's intended to return -1 (B goes before A), 0, (A and B are equal) or 1 (B goes after A).

[The `delegate` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e(v=vs.80).aspx) in this instance creates an anonymous function which is used as the comparator, and the body of that function calls `CompareTo` to compare the age property of the two people involved and return the result.

The result of calling this method on every potential pair of items (or some subset - I'm not sure exactly how `Sort` is implemented) is then used internally by the `Sort` method to figure out where to place the resulting item (in front of or behind of `p2`) in this example.

Answer (score 0):

List.Sort uses Quick sort algo to sort the list. The worst case complexity is `O(n ^ 2)`. Which means, in worst case, the delegate you provided will be called `n ^ 2` times, where `n` is the number of items in list. [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is like pointer to function.

It passes the two objects it wishes to compare, and the delegate you provided will return with `-1`, `0`, or `1`. If its -1 it means that p1 is lesser then p2, if 0 it means both objects are same, if 1 it means p1 is greater then p2. So, in the end, the delegate you provide and the values it returns will decide whether the list contains objects in `descending` or `ascending` order.

Answer (score 0):

Lets divide the problem so that you can understand each piece separately:

**The Sort method:**

This one takes a delegate, that contains the "how to" compare two elements of the list.
As soon as you teach the list how to compare to elements, then it can sort all elements, by comparing them in pairs.

**The inline delegate**

A inline delegate is the declaration of method, that does something.

```
 delegate(Person p1, Person p2) { return p1.age.CompareTo(p2.age);
```

This delegate is telling how to compare two Person objects. You are telling this to the compiler: *to compare p1 with p2, you should compare p1.age with p2.age*.

**Joining things**

The following line of code contains both elements, the sort method, and the "how to" compare two People objects.

```
people.Sort(delegate(Person p1, Person p2) { return p1.age.CompareTo(p2.age); });
```

So now it knows how to sort the list.