# C# - sorting by a property

Tags: c#, list, sorting, collections

I am trying to sort a collection of objects in C# by a custom property.
(For context, I am working with the Twitter API using the Twitterizer library, sorting Direct Messages into conversation view)

Say a custom class has a property named `label`, where `label` is a `string` that is assigned when the class constructor.

I have a `Collection` (or a `List`, it doesn't matter) of said classes, and I want to sort them all into separate `List`s (or `Collection`s) based on the value of `label`, and group them together.

At the moment I've been doing this by using a `foreach` loop and checking the values that way - a horrible waste of CPU time and awful programming, I know. I'm ashamed of it.

Basically I know that all of the data I have is there given to me, and I also know that it should be really easy to sort. It's easy enough for a human to do it with bits of paper, but I just don't know how to do it in C#.

Does anyone have the solution to this? If you need more information and/or context just ask.

Comment: `a horrible waste of CPU time and awful programming?` What are you talking about? If you have a collection, that's how you sort it - you iterate over the items. No real way around that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does sorting a C# List based on a property work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002605/how-does-sorting-a-c-sharp-list-based-on-a-property-work)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `Linq`'s [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx)?

```
var mySortedList = myCollection.OrderBy(x => x.PropertyName).ToList();
```

This is still going to loop through the values to sort - there's no way around that. This will at least clean up your code.

Answer (score 1):

You say sorting but it sounds like you're trying to divide up a list of things based on a common value.  For that you want [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx).

You'll also want [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) to switch from an [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb344977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as you'll presumably be wanting key based lookup.

I assume that the elements within each of the output sets will need to be sorted, so check out [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).  Since you'll undoubtedly be accessing each list multiple times you'll want to collapse it to a list or an array (you mentioned list) so I used [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
//Make some test data
var labels = new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
var rawMessages = new List<Message>();

for (var i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
    rawMessages.Add(new Message
    {
        Label = labels[i % labels.Length],
        Text = "Hi" + i,
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(i * Math.Pow(-1, i))
    });
}

//Group the data up by label
var groupedMessages = rawMessages.GroupBy(message => message.Label);

//Convert to a dictionary for by-label lookup (this gives us a Dictionary<string, List<Message>>)
var messageLookup = groupedMessages.ToDictionary(
            //Make the dictionary key the label of the conversation (set of messages)
            grouping => grouping.Key, 
            //Sort the messages in each conversation by their timestamps and convert to a list
            messages => messages.OrderBy(message => message.Timestamp).ToList());

//Use the data...
var messagesInConversationA = messageLookup["A"];
var messagesInConversationB = messageLookup["B"];
var messagesInConversationC = messageLookup["C"];
var messagesInConversationD = messageLookup["D"];
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like mlorbetske was correct in his interpretation of your question.  It sounds like you want to do grouping rather than sorting. I just went at the answer a bit differently

```
var originalList = new[] { new { Name = "Andy", Label = "Junk" }, new { Name = "Frank", Label = "Junk" }, new { Name = "Lisa", Label = "Trash" } }.ToList();

var myLists = new Dictionary<string, List<Object>>();

originalList.ForEach(x =>
    {
        if (!myLists.ContainsKey(x.Label))                
            myLists.Add(x.Label,new List<object>());
        myLists[x.Label].Add(x);

    });
```